# 12c - Mview refresh running longer on 1st run but,completes quickly on kill and rer-un

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have an Mview refresh(complete refresh) which runs at DB1 and it inturn it send the SELECT statement over dblink to DB2. Initially, when its run through privileged user it gets stuck runs for hours. When we investigated it shows the waits due to "Cell single block physical read" . However, when we kill the refresh either from DB1/DB2 and re-run it finishes quickly (2 to 10 mins) and wait event it shows (DB CPU or Cell multi block read - wait event). This is happening almost everyday for us.

We compared the execution plan for both the times it run on DB2, we don't see much change neither in plan_hash_value and SQL_ID nor in the execution plan. Does anybody know/or tell me what else am I missing in here and also any ideas how can resolve this problem.

```
1st run 
=======
   SNAP_ID   NODE BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME            SQL_ID        PLAN_HASH_VALUE        EXECS    AVG_ETIME        AVG_LIO        AVG_PIO
---------- ------ ------------------------------ ------------- --------------- ------------ ------------ -------------- --------------
     77142      3 01-OCT-19 07.15.05.867 AM      fybjvvtk09u2j                            0      912.735    1,090,393.0      440,686.0
     77143      3 01-OCT-19 07.30.00.413 AM      fybjvvtk09u2j                            0      842.735      989,493.0      467,590.0

kill and re-run
===============
   SNAP_ID   NODE BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME            SQL_ID        PLAN_HASH_VALUE        EXECS    AVG_ETIME        AVG_LIO        AVG_PIO
---------- ------ ------------------------------ ------------- --------------- ------------ ------------ -------------- --------------
     77144      4 01-OCT-19 07.45.01.936 AM      fybjvvtk09u2j                            1       98.649   14,272,525.0   14,591,211.0
```

Execution plan 1st run :-

```
Plan hash value: 3547885274

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                         |       |       |       |   447K(100)|          |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                 |                         |    27M|  1414M|  2004M|   447K  (2)| 00:00:18 |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                    |                         |    27M|  1414M|   281M|   180K  (4)| 00:00:08 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | AUDIT_LOG               |    11M|   146M|       |  8504   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |    PARTITION HASH ALL          |                         |    30M|  1200M|       |   165K  (4)| 00:00:07 |     1 |   256 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | DISA_DAILY_HHT_PUB      |    30M|  1200M|       |   165K  (4)| 00:00:07 |     1 |   256 |
|   6 |      SORT AGGREGATE            |                         |     1 |     6 |       |            |          |       |       |
|   7 |       INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| DISA_DAILY_HHT_PUB_IDX2 |     1 |     6 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("P"."AUDIT_LOG_ID"="AL"."AUDIT_LOG_ID")
   5 - storage("P"."AUDIT_LOG_ID"=)
       filter("P"."AUDIT_LOG_ID"=)

Execution plan on kill and re-run :- 
code
Plan hash value: 3547885274

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                         |       |       |       |   437K(100)|          |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                 |                         |    26M|  1360M|  1928M|   437K  (2)| 00:00:18 |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                    |                         |    26M|  1360M|   281M|   179K  (4)| 00:00:08 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | AUDIT_LOG               |    11M|   146M|       |  8504   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |    PARTITION HASH ALL          |                         |    29M|  1171M|       |   165K  (4)| 00:00:07 |     1 |   256 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | DISA_DAILY_HHT_PUB      |    29M|  1171M|       |   165K  (4)| 00:00:07 |     1 |   256 |
|   6 |      SORT AGGREGATE            |                         |     1 |     6 |       |            |          |       |       |
|   7 |       INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| DISA_DAILY_HHT_PUB_IDX2 |     1 |     6 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The user is different for the runs?  Is there anything limiting one user but not another, like resource manager or a profile?

Comment: Can you mask and share an imitation of your SQL? What are the CPU Times, Concurrency wait times, IO_CELL_OFFLOAD_ELIGIBLE_BYTES and IO_CELL_OFFLOAD_RETURNED_BYTES in both the runs?

Comment: @JonHeller Yes, The user is different. It goes like this. Everyday it runs at 6 AM CDT by the OWNER_RO(read only) account user and post 6:40 AM we get an email stating its running longer . We kill and re-run it from OWNER account.